# Free cropping a image

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, crop, opencv3.0

I'm new to image processing. My aim is to crop a particular region in a image which is irregular in shape that is taken from camera. How to do free cropping of that image and saving it using openCV 3 python ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: taking the bounding box of a mask based on the irregular shape?

Comment: may be some info here: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html

Comment: croping can be done using slicing: cropped= image[row_1:row_2,col1:col_2]

Comment: im asking like, we should able to crop as what we do in power point or paint @Jean-Pat

Comment: opencv != photoshop. wrong tool for the job, imho.

Comment: Fine and Thanks :-) @berak